# Embedded a External Video and Play the video in LWC Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have to embed an external video and play the video in LWC.
I only have **data-account="1752604059001"** and **data-video-id="4029697544001"**.
I have tried with **iframe** but it's not working.

Below is the code:

```
<video-js data-account="1752604059001" 
  data-player="default" 
  data-embed="default" 
  controls="" 
  data-video-id="4029697544001" 
  data-playlist-id="" 
  data-application-id="" 
  width="640" height="360"></video-js>
<script src="https://players.brightcove.net/1752604059001/default_default/index.min.js"></script>
```

NB: `Script` Tag is not working in lwc.
Reference link: https://player.support.brightcove.com/styling/customizing-player-appearance.html

Comment: You shouldn't be using random tags. Tags have a specific meaning and help people understand what a question is about. The "community" tag is meant for community sites (experience sites), which is a specific Salesforce feature.

Comment: I need to play different videos in Experience Cloud based on the  data-account="1752604059001" and data-video-id="4029697544001" <values will be different> using LWC.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this directly in LWC (or, strictly speaking, in a Salesforce Lightning Component). This has to do with the CSP (Content Security Policy) of Lightning. You could choose to embed a Visualforce page in an iframe or use a lightning:container to host the relevant markup and then expose it in an Aura component (this container isn't available for LWC).

Comment: Also If wanted download the file and store it as a Static Resource and then you can directly access the static resource file from LWC.